# Remove/Delete a feature from OpenLayers vector layer

Tags: openlayers-2

I have an OpenLayers layer with several vectors on it. I know the OpenLayers Feature ID (e.g. OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_241) and I would like to know how to remove this feature and only this feature?

I have considered deleting them all and then looping through an array to redraw them, but this seems a little inelegant, and long winded.

I have tried a variety of versions of the folllowing code:

```
layer.removeFeatures( featureID );
```

And

```
layer.removeFeatures( [featureID] );
```

And

```
layer.removeFeatures( {feature : featureID });
```

Etc...

All help is welcome!

Thanks

C

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think that OpenLayers is capable of removing a feature by providing the `featureID`. It seems like it can only remove a features by providing a feature or an array of features:

```
layer.removeFeatures(featureObject);
```

But you could instead locate the feature first and then remove the found feature:

```
layer.removeFeatures(layer.getFeatureById(featureID));
```

Or similar if its not the OpenLayers FeatureID you have, then

```
layer.removeFeatures(layer.getFeatureBy('myId', myID));
```

---

For OpenLayers **v6+** it's done in another way, considering that `layer` is a [VectorLayer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html):

```
let feature = layer.getSource().getFeatureById('featureID');
```

[`getFeatureById()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#getFeatureById)

Comment: I like the thinking!  The problems is though that the "layer.getFeatureById(featureID))" statement returns null, and so the removeFeature() doesnt work.  Im 100% that i have the right FeatureIDs though.... any more thoughts?

Comment: Scratch that. I was using the wrong featureID. Im using your second example and it works perfectly. Nice one!

Comment: I'm getting `layer.removeFeatures is not a function`

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
*layer.removeFeatures(featureObject);*
```

But i've got the feature as a global variable, maybe in other cases you should try to keep the feature ID in order to search to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to remove a single feature in Open Layers 6:

```
layer.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
```